# pip install mysql-connector-python installation error

Tags: python, mysql

I'm getting an error after installing MySQL Connector for Python 2.7.9 in Linux OS.

> Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-5nxFZ_/mysql-connector-python-rf/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-qLvsiw-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-5nxFZ_/mysql-connector-python-rf

```
Storing debug log for failure in /home/pi/.pip/pip.log
```

Searched a lot about this error couldn't find a satisfactory solution, please help me to sort out this error.

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

as Mysql-Python and all are not supported now. install mysql in linux and install the connector to connect to local mysql

Comment: Thank You @Exprator by using the above command I connected successfully to local Mysql but getting an error while connecting to remote Mysql server. "Remote Host is CentOS, tried giving grant permission in remote host by got an error as OperationalError "

Comment: for that you need to give permission to the remote host so that it can connect from other port, anyways i see you already accepted someones answer, hope you can connect to remote too :)

Comment: No, by using above comments I can connect to local MySQL server, not to remote MySQL server.

Comment: so the answer you accepted is allowing you to connect to the remote server? else you need to open the port of the centos for incoming requests

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't check the port in centOS. Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you for helping bro, now I can connect to remote MySQL server  Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

try this ,

```
pip install MySQL-python==1.2.5  # version specified
```

or

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but got an error like this "Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-cCkNRE/MySQL-python
Storing debug log for failure in /home/pi/.pip/pip.log"

Comment: check your pip.log what is the error occurs. seems pip need update

Comment: Updated PIP and can connect to local Mysql now, Thank you @user

Answer (score 1):

if you already installed required systems for python 2.7. Next, You should run this command:

sudo apt-get install python2.7-mysqldb

Comment: Thank you, I tried it. After running the program it is showing as                     
 ImportError: No module named mysql.connector